Exception encountered when calling layer 'keras_layer_1' (type KerasLayer)
I encountered an error while working on a google colab notebook.
the error is:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 17>()
15 model_url = "https://www.kaggle.com/models/google/resnet-v2/TensorFlow2/101-classification/2"  # Replace with your TensorFlow Hub model URL
16
---> 17 model = create_model(input_shape, output_shape, model_url)
18
19 # Now you can compile and train your model
7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/backend/common/keras_tensor.py in array(self)
59
60     def array(self):
---> 61         raise ValueError(
62             "A KerasTensor is symbolic: it's a placeholder for a shape "
63             "an a dtype. It doesn't have any actual numerical value. "
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'keras_layer_1' (type KerasLayer).
A KerasTensor is symbolic: it's a placeholder for a shape an a dtype. It doesn't have any actual numerical value. You cannot convert it to a NumPy array.
Call arguments received by layer 'keras_layer_1' (type KerasLayer):
• inputs=<KerasTensor shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32, sparse=None, name=keras_tensor_3>
• training=None
My code is as follows
import tensorflow_hub as hub

# Create a Functional model to wrap the KerasLayer
def create_model(input_shape, output_shape, model_url):
  inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
  x = hub.KerasLayer(model_url, trainable=False)(inputs)
  outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=output_shape, activation="softmax")(x)
  model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
  return model

# Example usage
input_shape = (224, 224, 3)  # Replace with your input shape
output_shape = 10  # Replace with your output shape
model_url = "https://www.kaggle.com/models/google/resnet-v2/TensorFlow2/101-classification/2"  # Replace with your TensorFlow Hub model URL

model = create_model(input_shape, output_shape, model_url)

# Now you can compile and train your model
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
# ... (training steps) ..```


i have tried everything to overcome this.  but couldnt find a solution. Someone help me


I tried to build an already existing deep learning model (resnet) taken from tensorflow hub for classification of dog breeds using images. but it throws error. 

